# Flask: A good way to replace GET parameter value in full_path

Tags: python, flask

We have a `full_path = request.full_path` with the following value

```
/v1/helloworld?year=2020&key=123&language=in&country=ID
```

We would like to replace `langauge` GET parameter value with the following value

```
/v1/helloworld?year=2020&key=123&language=id&country=ID
```

Currently, we are using the following way

```
full_path = request.full_path
if 'in' == request.args.get('language'):
    full_path = full_path.replace("language=in", "language=id")
```

We are not particular comfortable in using string `replace` to do the job. I was wondering, is there other better way to achieve so?

Comment: reqest.args is an immutableDict object. so i think this is a better option

Comment: Using `replace` will get the job done and seems to be a logical choice. What is your main concern/objection to using it? Your `if` condition is a fairly robust check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my generic approach to safely add, replace and remove GET parameters:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def alter_parameters(base_url, current_parameters, parameters_to_alter):
    new_parameters = {}

    # Replacing parameters existing in the current URL by the new value supplied
    for current_parameter_name, current_parameter_value in current_parameters.items():
        if current_parameter_name in parameters_to_alter:
            if parameters_to_alter[current_parameter_name] is not None:
                new_parameters[current_parameter_name] = parameters_to_alter[current_parameter_name]
        else:
            new_parameters[current_parameter_name] = current_parameter_value

    # Adding new parameters that do not exist in the current URL
    for parameter_to_alter_name, parameter_to_alter_value in parameters_to_alter.items():
        if (parameter_to_alter_name not in new_parameters) and parameter_to_alter_value is not None:
            new_parameters[parameter_to_alter_name] = parameter_to_alter_value
    
    if not new_parameters:
        return base_url
    else:
        return base_url+"?"+urlencode(new_parameters)
```

In Flask context, this is how it can be used:

```py
from flask import request
new_url = alter_parameters(request.path, request.args, {"page": 2})
```

Parameters can be added, edited, and removed (by specifying None as value) this way:

```
alter_parameters("https://example.net/search", {"name": "john", "page": 1}, {"sort": "descending"})
# => 'https://example.net/search?name=john&page=1&sort=descending'

alter_parameters("https://example.net/search", {"name": "john", "page": 1}, {"page": 2})
# => 'https://example.net/search?name=john&page=2'

alter_parameters("https://example.net/search", {"name": "john", "page": 1}, {"name": "jane", "page": None})
# => 'https://example.net/search?name=jane'
```

Thanks to the stdlib function `urllib.parse.urlencode`, the modified URL is sanitized as well:

```
alter_parameters("https://example.net/search", {"name": "john", "page": 1}, {"page": "1&hack=1"})
# => 'https://example.net/search?name=john&page=1%26hack%3D1'
```